# Android Unable to Retrieve JSON response [SC_406]

Tags: java, android, json, httpresponse

I have the code which basically retrieving a list of search result based on given keyword from TMDB (API ver.3, new API).

```
public String getPersonSearchResult(String keywords){
        String query = URLEncoder.encode(keywords);
        String TMDB_API_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?";
        String TMDB_LIMIT_LIST = "&page=1";
        String TMDB_QUERY = "&query=" + query;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;

        try
        {
            // ATTEMPT HTTP REQUEST
            String fullUrl = TMDB_API_URL + TMDB_API_KEY + TMDB_QUERY + TMDB_LIMIT_LIST;
            Log.w(APP_TAG, "TRYING [" + fullUrl + "]");

            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(fullUrl));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            }else{
                // FAILED REQUEST - CLOSE THE CONNECTION
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.w(APP_TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Log.w(APP_TAG, "FAILED TO RETRIEVE JSON DATA");
        }

        return responseString;
    }
```

The problem is that i always get 406 Status Code (Not Acceptable). When i tried to run the URL myself

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=<MY_API_KEY_HERE>&query=jennifer&page=1
```

It displays the JSON result correctly.

I am not sure why is this happening. Similar function is used to retrieve JSON value from other source and and it works perfectly.

this is their API docs regarding search: http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/#search

Can anyone points me to the right direction? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it 
Try using builder.scheme

```
    URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
    builder.setScheme("http").setHost("api.themoviedb.org").setPath("/3/search/person")
        .setParameter("api_key", YOURAPIKEY)
        .setParameter("page", 1)
        .setParameter("query", query)
    URI uri = builder.build();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);

.....
   response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(httpget ));
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, turns out i need to send a few parameter to header. See my answer below.

Comment: Glad you have figured it out. You can try this if you have time.

Comment: Oww great you figured it out by yourself.. thats nice it was what i felt would be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, by adding this:

```
HttpGet getObj = new HttpGet(fullUrl);
getObj.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Perhaps this is API specific requirement. Not sure though...

Answer (score 0):

I think its nothing to do with your code.. your code is perfect. The only problem might be with the API request method. Maybe they require some specific headers to be requested for in the request. Give a try with requesting headers like "("Accept", "application/json")" It might work..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String ret = null; try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HttpRequest", "" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;
```